# clojure.xml/parse: Whitespace-only text nodes ignored in mixed content

Tags: xml, clojure

I'm a newbie at clojure.xml, and Java XML libraries in general.

I'm getting surprised by the output from clojure.xml/parse. Text nodes that are made of whitespace only are getting ignored. This might be correct in an element-only node if there was a DOCTYPE declaration saying that the element can't have PCDATA, but whitespace is getting discarded without DOCTYPES and *even in mixed-content nodes,* which cannot have ignored whitespace.

test.clj:

```
(require '[clojure.xml :as x])

(prn (x/parse "test.xml"))
```

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x>

<y><z>AAA</z> BBB <z>AAA</z> <z>AAA</z></y>

</x>
```

output (missing text node between `<z>AAA</z>` and `<z>AAA</z>`):

```
{:tag :x, :attrs {:xml:space "preserve"}, :content
  [{:tag :y, :attrs nil, :content
    [{:tag :z, :attrs nil, :content ["AAA"]}
     " BBB "
     {:tag :z, :attrs nil, :content ["AAA"]}
     {:tag :z, :attrs nil, :content ["AAA"]}]}]}
```

I'm using Clojure 1.2.0. Is this a bug, or is this somehow how it ought to behave? (Even adding a xml:space="preserve" attribute doesn't work.)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a bug. I'll rearrange the test.xml file so that it looked like the ouput from test.clj:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x>

  <y>
    <z>AAA</z>
    BBB
    <z>AAA</z>
    <z>AAA</z>
  </y>

</x>
```

In this file 'x' is a root element that contains 'y' element that contains 'z' elements and "BBB" as a string. You could look at [xml specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-logical-struct) about the logical structure of a xml file.

Returning to Clojure, Clojure [uses SAX parser](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/59b65669860a1f33825775494809e5d500c19c63/src/clj/clojure/xml.clj#L78) that is based on events-driven system. If you are familiar with java (which you should if you don't) try to play with ["Sample SAX2 application"](http://www.saxproject.org/quickstart.html).

This is the output from the "Sample SAX2 application" with test.xml as an argument:

```
Start document
Start element: x
Characters:    "\n\n"
Start element: y
Start element: z
Characters:    "AAA"
End element: z
Characters:    " BBB "
Start element: z
Characters:    "AAA"
End element: z
Characters:    " "
Start element: z
Characters:    "AAA"
End element: z
End element: y
Characters:    "\n\n"
End element: x
End document
```

And copy of your test.clj output:

```
{:tag :x, :attrs {:xml:space "preserve"}, :content
  [{:tag :y, :attrs nil, :content
    [{:tag :z, :attrs nil, :content ["AAA"]}
     " BBB "
     {:tag :z, :attrs nil, :content ["AAA"]}
     {:tag :z, :attrs nil, :content ["AAA"]}]}]}
```

As can be seen `clojure.xml/parse` (from the test.clj output) just drops '\n' (\newline) and ' ' (\space) [elements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29) from the xml document but other elements are the same. If you are interesting why the elements is dropped you can look at [clojure.xml/content-handler](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/59b65669860a1f33825775494809e5d500c19c63/src/clj/clojure/xml.clj#L26) source and look at the `push-chars` function:

```
push-chars (fn []
             (when (and (= *state* :chars)
                        (some (complement #(Character/isWhitespace (char %))) (str *sb*)))
               (set! *current* (push-content *current* (str *sb*)))))
```

And:

```
user> (map (complement #(Character/isWhitespace (char %))) [\newline \space \a])
(false false true)
```

Update: If you want to preserve spaces try to arrange an xml file like this. (for me it works):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<x>

<y xml:space="preserve"><z>AAA</z> BBB <z>AAA</z> <z>AAA</z></y>

</x>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. While I'm still wondering whether clojure.xml is obeying the XML standard by stripping whitespace nodes from mixed content, and adding xml:space to every mixed-content node is unacceptable, you gave me the *precise location* where the problem is occuring, which is wonderful! Commenting out the `(some (complement ...))` form preserves whitespace! Hurrah!